# How-to-install, lubuntu-core_0.94_amd64.deb

Tags: lubuntu, deb, ubuntu-core, coreboot

I want to make a *small as possible* Lubuntu. I have downloaded Desktop, Alt and Mini.

What I have no idea about is, Core....
lubuntu-core_0.94_amd64.deb
I don't know how to do a fresh install with a .deb file.

Is this the same as the new Ubuntu Core/snaps?

Answer (score 0):

It's Just a Desktop environment. You can use gdebi instller to install if you miss any dependencies for that core it will download the dependencies and install for you.

For install gdebi package:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

use gdebi applicaion to install your deb file.

After restarting you have to select the lubuntu session for switching between you current linux version and lubuntu.

Comment: "use gdebi installer to install" Ok, but I'm starting from "a fresh install with a .deb file." What environment do I need for gdebi? Is this something I run from a Live CD and use gdebi to write it to the new HDD?

Comment: I don't get it, for starter You want to install light weight linux in your system right?

Comment: @ Ghostranger: Yes, just the Linux/Ubuntu kernel and the Lubuntu desktop... Maybe a way to download programs/apps, with a NIC. How do I do that with a .DEB?

Comment: deb is a package manager you get all sorts of application in deb. you can find the application in Ubuntu repository and you can find deb file in  [https://packages.ubuntu.com/](https://packages.ubuntu.com/)